# how to fetch the entire page content from a multiple pages with a keyword match in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

i am trying a small example like if a keyword matches in a particular page among multiple pages then i need to fetch the entire content of that particular page. the page look like as below.

98339-93-05-1,PROD,**2**, 288.000, 40.800, 34.500, "Slate_Pro_Light", 9.0, 8, "981-2535"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,**2**, 324.240, 40.800, 7.485, "Slate_Pro_Light", 9.0, 2, "or"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,**2**, 333.360, 40.800, 19.473, "Slate_Pro_Light", 9.0, 5, "email"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,2, 288.000, 31.440, 104.442, "Slate_Pro_Light", 9.0, 24, "jmcgaha@farmersagent.com"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,2, 63.120, 14.160, 22.312, "**Slate_Pro_Bk_Condensed**", 8.0, 7, "56-6177"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,2, 91.920, 14.160, 7.880, "**Slate_Pro_Bk_Condensed**", 8.0, 3, "1st"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 101.280, 14.160, 19.160, "Slate_Pro_Bk_Condensed", 8.0, 7, "Edition"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 127.920, 14.160, 12.232, "Slate_Pro_Bk_Condensed", 8.0, 4, "4-14"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 45.120, 704.160, 66.239, "Slate_Pro_Medium", 13.5, 11, "Declaration"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 113.760, 704.160, 28.350, "Slate_Pro_Medium", 13.5, 4, "Page"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 144.480, 704.160, 61.890, "Slate_Pro_Light", 13.5, 11, "(continued)"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 45.120, 661.200, 60.491, "Slate_Pro_MediumIta", 13.5, 9, "Mortgagee"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 107.760, 661.200, 6.142, "Slate_Pro_MediumIta", 13.5, 1, "/"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 115.920, 661.200, 31.138, "Slate_Pro_MediumIta", 13.5, 5, "Other"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 149.280, 661.200, 42.081, "Slate_Pro_MediumIta", 13.5, 8, "Interest"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 45.120, 645.600, 11.720, "Slate_ProIta", 10.0, 3, "1st"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 58.560, 645.600, 43.320, "Slate_ProIta", 10.0, 9, "Mortgagee"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 244.080, 645.600, 19.150, "Slate_ProIta", 10.0, 4, "Loan"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 264.960, 645.600, 32.100, "Slate_ProIta", 10.0, 6, "Number"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 45.120, 631.680, 26.040, "Slate_Pro_Light", 10.0, 6, "Bryant"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 72.960, 631.680, 19.910, "Slate_Pro_Light", 10.0, 4, "Bank"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 45.120, 619.680, 12.230, "Slate_Pro_Light", 10.0, 2, "PO"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 59.040, 619.680, 14.710, "Slate_Pro_Light", 10.0, 3, "Box"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 75.360, 619.680, 10.040, "Slate_Pro_Light", 10.0, 2, "46"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 45.120, 607.680, 42.100, "Slate_Pro_Light", 10.0, 11, "Huntsville,"
98339-93-05-1,PROD,3, 89.040, 607.680, 9.770, "Slate_Pro_Light", 10.0, 2, "AL"

so if a column matches with the keyword **Slate_Pro_Bk_Condensed** then i need to fetch the entire data.
 in the above the keyword matches in page **3** so now  i need to fetch all the data in page 3.

so please help me on this to resolve using Map Reduce program

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to split the pages into files and use FileInputFormat to process them in MR.
Then use java regex to check if a certain page contains 'Slate_Pro_Bk_Condensed' for example.
You can iterate over the rows in each page to slighly improve performance - once you find your string you can skip to the next page.